# Reference for Hopf algebra applications to Feynman diagrams

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, hopf-algebras

I need to give a talk about Hopf algebras and I would like to give a (at least) 5 minutes introduction using Feynman diagrams as a motivation. I'm looking for a not-so-heavy reference explaining how the notions of product and coproduct arises from Feynman diagrams.

Comment: If you want to do this in 5 minutes, my guess is that what you want does not exist. You can use combinatorial examples (browsing the book by Aguiar, for example, or the papers of Gian Carlo Rota on applicattions of Hopf algebras to combinatorics should give you ideas)

Comment: I'm doing that as well, I just want to talk about Feynman diagrams because my talk is may 11th, the anniversary of Feynman

Comment: I changed the question a little bit: I just need a motivation for "cutting" and "uncutting" in Feyman diagrams, after that I would go with some examples "à la Rota"